# Possibility to generate invalid/impossible type with records

Tags: typescript

Am i missing something, or should below cause an error in TS, but doesn't?

```
const sy = Symbol();
type A<T extends Record<string, unknown[]>> = (...args: T[keyof T]) => void;
type B = A<{ [sy]: 0 }>;
//   ^? type B = (...args: 0) => void
```

To me, is looks like string index signatures are assumed to cover all property-keys, while they don't cover symbols, allowing to generate an invalid/impossible type.

This works in older versions as well, so I'd assume there is an issue/discussion about it somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: A [simpler related case](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCeMC8MDK8C2AjEAbAFAJQDcAUFPAA4CmMAGsjAErWgBOAJgDzRsCWYAOYAaGAFcwAazAgA7mAB8pUJFgAPAFz1GAbxgBtBAF0tARgBMAZhgBfIA)

Comment: In the sense, that it doesn't trigger an excess property error for the given literal, I'd say yes.